# What's the difference between 水 and 湯

Tags: word-choice, words

I start by saying that I'm a beginner in Japanese and maybe my question will seem obvious to you.

I've been told by Japanese people that there's a difference between 水 and 湯.
I understand that 湯 means "hot water", but isn't it the same if I said あつい水?

Comment: As a native speaker, I don't feel あつい水 is immediately ungrammatical, but it can't avoid sounding like "invisible pink unicorn".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although most dictionaries or word lists translate "mizu" simply as "water", the actual meaning of "mizu" is "cold/cool water" whereas "o-yu" is "warm/hot water". So to a Japanese "atsui mizu" sounds like "hot cold water". They can understand it because they know in English there is a word called "water" including both "mizu" and "o-yu", but a Japanese person would never express it that way.

The criterion basically is the human body temperature. Everything below it is "mizu", above it "o-yu". It is possible to say "tsumetai mizu" however in order to stress that the water is really very cold.

Comment: Note that "mizu" can also be used to mean just water, when the temperature is not a matter at all (I believe this is why we can understand "atsui mizu").

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the other answers and regarding the phrase あつい水, I'd like note this is possible *in certain contexts.*

---

An article on *Tokyo Language Center*:

> **誤用？「熱い水」**
>
> 「地球の環境」がテーマの番組で、深海を探査するシーンで「摂氏２００度をこえる熱い水がふきだしている」というフレーズが聞こえてきました。
>
> このシーンでは「摂氏２００度をこえるお湯」はそぐわないんですね。なんか科学的な雰囲気が壊れてしまい、「温泉でのんびり」という感じになってしまいそうで・・・
>
> 「ゆ」はただ単に「温度」の問題だけではなく、「生活」といった文脈の上に存在しているようです。

[source](http://tokyolc.seesaa.net/s/article/33602240.html)

(summary: お湯 has got a cultural aspect to it. It sounds inappropriate in a purely scientific context.)

---

An article on *ShareWIS press* using it in a similar context:

> **海底にある ”特異点” ホットスポットが熱い！**
>
> 海の水って冷たいですよね。でも海底には熱水系といって、暖かい（というか**熱い）水**の環境があるのをご存知でしょうか。

[source](http://press.share-wis.com/hot-spot)

---

A book titled **熱い水のような砂** by 桐野 夏生 (ISBN-10: 438785121X):

> 日本女性と冒険家の砂漠ロマンスです。ある理由があって、サハラ行きにＯＫしたフィルこと、イギリス貴族で冒険家のフィリップ・コンウェイ。 日本から遥々〜会いにやって来た日本女性、小津香子に次第に惹かれていくことに…

[(beginning of an amazon review)](http://www.amazon.co.jp/review/R1649JDPLC1VNM/)

お湯 is something nice. The scorching hot sand of the Sahara is not.

---

A basic introduction to thermodynamics on *NHK*:

> **熱効率と不可逆変化**
>
> [image]
>
> 最初に出てきたペルチェ素子を使った装置を思い出してください。
>
> 下にある**熱い水**から、上の冷たい水に熱が移動してプロペラが回りましたね。
>
> 時間が経って２つのビンに入っている水の温度はほぼ同じになりました。

[source](http://www.nhk.or.jp/kokokoza/library/tv/butsurikiso/archive/resume022.html)

---

And a a short article I found talking about that temperature is not the only difference:

> **お湯は熱い水**
>
> **狭山市立教育センター**
>
> **所長  澤 田  剛**
>
> 「お湯」は、英語では「hot water」になります。では「hot water」を直訳すると、どうなるでしょう。「熱い水」ですね。つまり、英語話者にとっては「お湯」はただ「温度が上がった水」でしかないのです。しかし、日本人にとって「湯」と「水」には、**単に温度の高い低いではない違いがある**ようです。「お湯」は、「お風呂」や「温泉」（＝いでゆ）を意味しますし、「湯ざまし」「ぬるま湯」等の言葉がある通り、一度沸かした「水」は、冷めても「お湯」です。風呂が沸いたと思い足を入れたら冷たかった。すると「なんだ、まだ水じゃないか」ということになります。

[source](http://www.sayama-stm.ed.jp/center/index/syokan/H26/2607.pdf)

---

Which explains this as well, from 中学数学の基本問題 on geisya.or.jp:

> **食塩水の濃度**
>
> [...]
>
> ※　Ａ君がａ(゜Ｃ)の冷たい水ｂ(ｇ)とｃ(゜Ｃ)の**熱い水**ｄ(ｇ)を，Ｂ君が，ｅ(゜Ｃ)の冷たい水ｆ（ｇ）とｇ(゜Ｃ)の熱い水ｈ(ｇ)を持っていて，各自の水を混ぜる場合にも，上の問題と同様の取り扱いになります．

[source](http://www.geisya.or.jp/~mwm48961/math3/m2salt03.htm)

Comment: That's what the site self-evaluation is for: reviewing old questions ツ

Answer (score 5):

The original difference between 水 and お湯 is that the latter was prepared, but the former was never. Hence, the honorific お is an indicator that this has been done for the listener's well being. Using temperature as a divider is for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 4):

In general, We call what you might think of as "あつい水" -> "(お)湯". 
"あつい水" is not used in conversation for that meaning.

However, "あつい(お)湯" is correct and can be used.